# Floor of integer to the nearest 10,000

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

If possible can anyone advise the best way to get the floor of an integer e.g. 388,000 should always return the floor of 380,000.

Thats to say the floor should always be rounded down to 10,000.

I saw math.floor(300.16):

Result:

300.0

However this function only applies the floor to the decimal places.

All help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Comment: 10000*int(math.floor(x/10000)) should work. Also x - (x % 10000).

Comment: Round to nearest 10000 of 388000 is 390000

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help, it's much appreciated. Indeed I shall apply this to a series in pandas however I will apply it as part of using iterrows on that column since each rows rounding will be conditional upon another value in another series of the same row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can first subtract 5000 from your number and then round to 4 place before the decimal points:

```
round(388000-5000, -4)
380000

round(383000-5000, -4)
380000
```

Or to use floor function with a trick:

```
math.floor(388000/10000)*10000
380000
```

Comment: Since OP tagged `numpy`, one could also use `np.round` which similarly accepts negative `decimals` argument.

Answer (score 0):

I would divide the given integer by 10,000.0 (with type cast to float), then floor and then multiply by 10.000 (with type cast to integer). Should do the job.

Maybe your language cuts the decimals when you divide integers, than you may spare the casting and flooring and just divide and multiply.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to perform this operation on a pandas series, given this question is tagged with `pandas`.

**UPDATED: Thanks to GZ0**

`s = s // 10000 * 10000`

Comment: `s // 10000` is better than `(s / 10000).astype(int)`. And the same expression can be used for regular integers as well.

Comment: Thanks Sam it works well also, I appreciate your help